# React: onClick() event provides wrong cursor coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please educate me on the following issue. I have a React component. On mouse button click, I'm getting the cursor position and handle that (use the `onClick` event).

The issue happens when I mouse-click and then quickly move the cursor. In result, `onClick()` handler gets an event containing not proper mouse position - not where the click happened, but where the cursor stopped after the quick move.

In addition to `onClick()`, I have `onMouseMove()` handler. And on that quick cursor move, multiple `onMouseMove` events get fired before the `onClick` event.

Why does this happen? Is this because of the lower priority of the `onClick`? Then, how to get the position of mouse-click?

Below is a simplified code that demonstrates the issue:

```
import React from 'react'

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    onClick(e) {
        console.log('ON CLICK, clientX:', e.clientX)
    }

    onMouseMove(e) {
        console.log('on move, clientX:', e.clientX)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div style={{width: 300, height: 300, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}
           onClick={this.onClick} onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}/>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need the value of `clientX` exactly the moment you press the mouse click, you should use [`onmousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) (`onMouseDown` for React) instead.

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-kapitsa-uktht?file=/src/App.js) is a working example.

---

For `onclick` to be triggered, both `mousedown` + `mouseup`(button release) of your left mouse button should occur. Thus, if the mouse is moved in the meantime (while you are still holding the button), your log will end up with the value of your final position.

Comment: `onMouseDown` works well! Thank you much! Do you have an understanding of what is happening with `onClick`?

Comment: I have extended my answer to also cover this. Let me know if you need anything else. If this covers your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to help anyone looking for the same issue in the future.

Comment: I've added `onMouseUp` event. Then, I see the sequence: `onMouseDown` -> `onMouseMove` -> `onMouseUp` -> `onClick`. So, `onClick` works as it should. You're right, thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps from the response from Michalis, But I found incorrect values in the event, this is caused probably by React, I've found the way to work around it here's what I've found.

The `clientX` and `clientY` are bigger than the width and height of the target element when clicking in the right-bottom corner. See the image example showing the error.[image]

Also, there is a problem with this approach with touch devices I created a new sandbox that works for both desktop and touch devices, you can check it out in the link below.
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-click-and-touch-detection-gc3p2?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

when you "click", are you performing both a "mousedown" and a "mouseup"? in other words, are you releasing the mouse before moving it? the "click" event fires only when both the mousedown and mouseup events have occurred on the div, so if you go mousedown, then move the cursor, then do mouseup, the click will register in the location where you did the mouseup, not the mousedown.